# The equation of a sphere of a given radius, whose center belongs to a given line and it is passing through a point

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

Determine the equation of a sphere of radius $\sqrt{5}$, whose center belongs to the line
$$d : {{x}\over1} = {{y-1}\over -1} = {{z+2}\over 1} $$
and it is passing through the point $A(0,2,-1)$

`My solution`:
If the center belongs to the line $d$, it means that the line is tangent to the sphere and so the distance from the center $C(x,y,z)$ to the line $d$ is equal with R = $\sqrt{5}$. After doing all the computation I got the following result:
$$2x^2+2y^2+2z^2-6x-6y+2xy-2xz+2yz+6 = \sqrt{15}$$
Now, this isn't really the equation of the sphere I'm looking for because the radius here is $\sqrt{15}$. Could you tell me where I went wrong in my solution?

Comment: You say "If the center belongs to the line d, it means that the line is tangent to the sphere". I rather think that this means that there is a plane tangent to the sphere orthogonal to the line. You may try to understand the situation by looking at a circle through a point, a line passing through the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the equations
$$d : {{x}\over1} = {{y-1}\over -1} = {{z+2}\over 1} $$
we get $$y=1-x;\;z=x-2$$
So the line $d$ has parametric equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=1 - t\\
z= -2 + t\\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus the center of the sphere has coordinates $C(t,1-t,-2+t)$

The sphere passes through $A(0,2,-1)$ and radius is $r=\sqrt 5$

Therefore $AC^2=5$ that is
$$t^2+(t+1)^2+(t-1)^2=5$$
which gives $t=\pm 1$

The center of the sphere can be $$C_1(1,0,-1);\;C_2(-1,2,-3)$$